# Credentials Tag

Tags: discussion

while creating a new question I noticed there was a `[Credentials]` tag, I was going to edit the Wiki but then I thought it was actually a pretty useless tag.

So I'm suggesting it be deleted or made into a synonyms with `[Permissions]` which any question regarding credentials will be related to.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the old AuthZ vs. AuthN dichotomy. These are actually two different things.

Perhaps authorization could be merged with permissions and authentication with credentials, but even then...